# Stop iPhone from vibrating when recording a voice message in Signal or WhatsApp

Tags: iphone, vibrate

Whenever I start a voice message recording in Signal or WhatsApp my iPhone SE vibrates. This vibration can be heard at the beginning of the voice message. The phone also vibrates at the end of the voice message, when I release the "microphone" button.

Since this happens in two messengers independently, I suspect that this is a system setting. I was not able to find an option to turn this off. The phone does not vibrate when I use the built-in "Voice Memos" app.

Neither the silent mode nor the do-not-disturb mode have an effect on the vibration.

**How can I stop my iPhone SE from vibrating whenever I start and stop a voice recording in a messenger?**

<sub>iOS 12.0 (16A366), 
iPhone SE (MP832DN/A)</sub>

Comment: For me, recording something in WhatsApp is fine but I get the annoying buzz at the beginning of Signal messages. Haven't figured out how to fix that yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a system setting and can be fixed in settings.

Go to Settings -> Sound and turn off "Vibrate on Ring".

[image]

Comment: This does not work. I don't have enough reputation to downvote.

Comment: @problemofficer for me it does. Make sure you follow the instructions correctly

Comment: My iPhone is usually in silent mode, so for me turning off "Vibrate on Silent" stopped the buzzing. However - in Signal - there's still a split second of static at the beginning of voice recordings, just a little quieter than before.

Comment: Also, i don't want to turn off vibrate system-wide. And in WhatsApp the voice recordings are fine even when it vibrates when I start recording.